# PHP / htaccess redirect via GET

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want:

- `sub.domain.com` to load `index.php`
- `sub.domain.com?s=custom` to load `/custom/index.php`

I'm doing this right now:

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(custom)/?$ index.php?subject=$1
```

and in `index.php` I have this:

```
if($_GET['s'] == 'custom') {
   header( 'Location: http://sub.domain.com/custom/index.php' ) ;
}
```

... but is it possible to do the redirect via htaccess itself depending on the GET variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could check query string with RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=custom
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ custom/index.php [L]
```

With this, it redirects all requests with existing "custom" get parameter to index.php, and this can be extended :)

Idea: http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html

Comment: shouldn't it be `s=(.*)` instead of `custom=(.*)` ?

Comment: Thanks. also it currently redirects any query string to /custom, what if I want to redirect individually?

Comment: Also MAYBE this will work: `RewriteRule s=custom custom/index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use "RedirectMatch"

```
RedirectMatch ^sub.domain.com?s=custom$  /custom/index.php
```

Maybe youll need to play with the regex abit